# How can I draw a line through a group of points in R?

Tags: r, line, normal-distribution

So, I have a table `qb` that contains a column, `Total_Half_PPR` and `Tier`. With the code below, I added a column containing a normal distribution of `Total_Half_PPR` for each Tier

```
for(tier in unique(qb$Final.Tier)){
  qb$Norm[qb$Final.Tier == tier] <- dnorm(qb$Total_Half_PPR[qb$Final.Tier == tier], 
                                          mean = mean(qb$Total_Half_PPR[qb$Final.Tier == tier]), 
                                          sd = sd(qb$Total_Half_PPR[qb$Final.Tier == tier])) 
}
```

Once that's done, I plotted each of the normal distributions on one plot, by adding a color to them. (I created a subset that only contained certain tiers of interest)

```
subset.data <- subset(qb, Final.Tier %in% c(1,2,3,4))

p <- ggplot(data = subset.data, aes(x = Total_Half_PPR, y = Norm)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = Final.Tier))
```

Here is the resulting plot:
[Normal Distribution Plot for each Tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euz9J.png)

Right now, I am just using a different color to indicate the curve of a given tier. How do i got about plotting a line for each of the normal distributions shown in the pictures, instead of the scatter plot?

Comment: general way with https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_function.html

Comment: Could you help me understand how to use this code on the link in my case?

base + stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red") +stat_function(fun = dt, colour = "blue", args = list(df = 1))

That's the function they used to plot two graphs, but im having a hard time translating that to my case

Comment: you already have the mean and sd for each normal distribution. Then plot each normal distribution passing mean and sd through stat_function args